# How to move/swap a std::vector efficiently and thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, vector, thread-safety, move

Imagine a thread which continuously writes to a `vector` of `string`s which is being collected every now and then by another thread (see code).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

// some public vector being filled by one and consumed by another
// thread
static std::vector<std::string> buffer;

// continuously writes data to buffer (has to be fast)
static const auto filler(std::thread([] {
  for (size_t i = 0;; ++i) {
    buffer.push_back(std::to_string(i));
  }
}));

// returns collected data and clears the buffer being written to
std::vector<std::string> fetch() {
  return std::move(buffer);
}

// continuously fetch buffered data and process it (can be slow)
int main() {
  size_t expected{};
  for(;;) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    const auto fetched(fetch());
    for (auto && e : fetched) {
      size_t read(std::stoi(e));
      std::cout << read << " " << expected << std::endl;
      assert(read == expected);
      ++expected;
    }
  }
}
```

The provided example generally does what I want it to do but it crashes because it's not thread safe. Obvious approaches would be

- to secure the shared vector using a `lock_guard`
- using two buffers and an atomic pointer
- using a thread safe `vector` implementation.

The provided scenario seems very simple to me. I don't think I need a thread safe vector because that would cover a lot more scenarios at the cost of performance.

Using a mutex or swapping between two instances of the vector seem plausible to me but I wonder if there is some solution specially made to 'atomically grab all data and leave an empty container'.

Maybe there's an obvious solution and it's just time to go to bed for me?

**Important note**: this question is somewhat academical since *performance* is not (necessarily) a real issue here. The provided example gets throttled by about 15% but there is hardly any 'real' work being done. I think in a real world example the benefit would be about 2-5%

Comment: All other things being equal, I would choose the solution that spends the least amount of time doing anything while keeping a mutex locked.  I would lean toward the atomic pointer-swap for that reason.

Comment: It looks to be a single-producer-single-consumer problem. And a wait-free ring-buffer queue is often the best solution. See benchmarks of different queues [here](https://max0x7ba.github.io/atomic_queue/html/benchmarks.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would not recommend to have a non-const static variable. So I propose to encapsulate vector with a class with the following interface

```
class ValuesHolder
{
public:
    void push_back(std::string value);
    std::vector<std::string> take();
};
```

The second note about 'atomically grab all data and leave an empty container' - you could make this trick with swapping pointers but the main issue is that `push_back` should be in a sync with it (during the push_back is executed vector shouldn't be moved). Otherwise there may be issues with the following workflow

Thead 1                                    Thread 2
auto values = holder.take();               // push_back starts before take
for (const auto& value : values)           // but value is inserted during the iteration
{...}

So the first option is just to lock during both calls:

```
class ValuesHolder
{
public:
    void push_back(std::string value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        values.push_back(std::move(value));
    }

    std::vector<std::string> take()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        return std::move(values);
    }

private:
    std::mutex mut;
    std::vector<std::string> values;
};
```

Otherwise you could switch from std::vector to lock-free stack container. However the performance should be accurately measured since the number of allocations can increase, so the performance can be worser.

Comment: yes, this is how I implemented it now - locking the vector every time I do a `push_back` does not affect the performance in any measurable way. so this is the cleanest solution in my eyes.